# Cast dataframe groupby to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-excel

All I need is to cast a DataFrameGroupBy object to a DataFrame in order to export to excel using `df.to_excel()`. When I try to do `df_groupby = pd.DataFrame(df_groupby)` I get the error: `PandasError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!`

Original df:

```
 df = DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
                       'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
                 'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
                        'two', 'two', 'one', 'three'],
                 'C' : randn(8), 'D' : randn(8)})

In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
 A      B         C         D
 0  foo    one  0.469112 -0.861849
 1  bar    one -0.282863 -2.104569
 2  foo    two -1.509059 -0.494929
 3  bar  three -1.135632  1.071804
 4  foo    two  1.212112  0.721555
 5  bar    two -0.173215 -0.706771
 6  foo    one  0.119209 -1.039575
 7  foo  three -1.044236  0.271860
```

`grouped = df.groupby('A')`

I want to export `grouped` to excel.

Comment: A groupby object doesn;'t do anything until you've performed an operation on it. Can you show what you're trying to achieve here, as it sounds like all you may need is to set a multi-index

Comment: I had an original df that I grouped on and I want to export that result to excel except that it's now a dataframe groupby object.

Comment: Please show raw data and code to demonstrate your problem. The point being that when you perform an operation on a groupby object, it returns a df or series. If you just groupby on a column(s) it's just metadata for *how* to perform the groupby.

Comment: Updated to show an example.

Comment: As I've already stated just grouping on a column produces an object that describes how to perform the grouping, are you wanting this: `df.set_index('A').to_excel()`?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what you want to achieve. So here goes for a set of possible answers.

But first: the bad news. A groupby object is not a DataFrame, and it cannot be saved to excel (or simply turned into a DataFrame).

1) If you just want to sort the DataFrame, this will also "group" things

```
df.sort('A').to_excel('filename.xls')
```

2) If you want to get rid of the default index in Excel

```
df.sort('A').to_excel('filename.xls', index=None)
```

3) If you want each group on its own worksheet in Excel

```
grouped = df.groupby('A')
from pandas import ExcelWriter
writer = ExcelWriter('filename.xls')
for k, g in grouped:
    g.to_excel(writer, k)
writer.save()
```

4) You can concatenate the groups into a new DataFrame. But this is pretty much the same as the first sort option above

```
grouped = df.groupby('A')
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for k, g in grouped:
    new_df = pd.concat([new_df, g], axis=0)
new_df.to_excel('filename.xls')
```

5) A first exercise in meaninglessness ... a pass through transform function ... but this just gives you your DataFrame back ...

```
df = df.set_index('A')
grouped = df.groupby(level=0)
grouped.transform(lambda x: x).to_excel('filename.xls')
```

6) Another exercise in meaninglessness ... this time with a pass through filter function ...

```
# start with initial data
grouped = df.groupby('A')
grouped.filter(lambda x: True).to_excel('filename.xls')
```

7) If you want to look inside of the groupby you can always do the following ... (but note this does not save to Excel) ...

```
# start with initial data
grouped = df.groupby('A')
groups = dict(list(grouped))
print[groups['foo'])
print[groups['bar'])
```